# How could zombies infect the population of an entire town?

Tags: warfare, apocalypse, diseases, zombies

There is a zombie apocalypse scenario where one zombie appeared in a small town in America. Would it be possible or plausible for them to take over? My problem is that the military would just quickly kill off any infected before they are able to spread. What traits would help the zombies spread?

Here is the description of the zombies:

- They are very slow  - 1 mph - and can't run.
- They can die and are just like humans in terms of squishiness
- They can't understand complex reasoning
- They can be tricked and misled by a recorded scream
- They do not kill if they bite humans; they make humans become zombies
- Humans transform into zombies in about 12 hours
- Zombies do not sleep
- The virus can only spread by bites

I will add more if needed.

Comment: This is trivially easy. If ten blind-drunk thugs appeared in America the military will not be able to contain them because of the [Posse Comitatus Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posse_Comitatus_Act) of 1878. It is the job of the *police* to deal with intoxicated hooligans. The military forces are not allowed to participate in enforcing public peace (unless exceptions, which don't apply).

Comment: so does this mean mass of civilian crushing them is fine?

Comment: From our [help/on-topic], "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story. If a system, event or element of the world is causing you problems we are here to help. If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." This is an off-topic storybuilding question about character choices and actions. Please read the fist two bullets of the [help] carefully. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you type the following in the site's search bar, "is:question zombie apocalypse" you'll find a lot of questions have been asked on this subject. Please take the time to discover if your question has been fundamentally answered before posting a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Your query is now in the Reopen queue, but I don't see how it has fundamentally changed since being closed.  Basically, it looks like any good old American city-burning mob ought to be able to put paid to ten zombies.  You really need to focus on what your issue is with the military. As it stands, I have to concur with JBH that the question is basically story based: it comes down to choices and actions of military planners & officers, rather than anything inherent in the physics of weapons or in the science of military deployment.

Comment: You might want to watch "The Last Train to Busan." They have fast "zombies", and it only takes one to infect a crowd, which then goes on to infect many more.

Comment: anyone have a stradgy for the zombies to face the whole might of the military?

Comment: Ever played The Last of Us? The plot for that game might be the answer you seek about the military failing to contain a zombie apocalypse.

Answer (score 2):

Assume a future where the police are defunded, and the military are well controlled.

The military can't operate there, as in this country, it is illegal for the military to be used to kill civilians. As such, they won't be deployed till things get very bad.

The police can't operate because it was decided that the police were no longer needed because the police are the racist patriarchal arm of oppression of an authoritarian state, and the people felt it would be better if they were replaced by mediators and people to start dialogue. Mediators, sadly, turn out to not be great at handling zombies, and zombies do not start dialogue. They bite people.

The zombies have strength of the dead and durability. Their immunity to pain means they can overpower people and resist the few people who have weapons.

People initially assume the sick people wandering around are drunks. They don't expect the bites, and think it's just crazy homeless people. A lot of people get sick, including several mediators. Twelve hours later the infection explodes outwards.

Eventually, the zombies attack key power lines, and several nuclear power plant meltdowns happen. This causes widespread disruption, and in the chaos the military can't effectively coordinate a response. The apocalypse happens.

Comment: I do not know how to judge the tone of this answer. On one hand it says (a) defunding the police is a bad idea but also (b) the reason it is a bad idea is that is makes us susceptible to zombie invasion. Please advise.

Comment: If you live in a world where zombie invasions are likely, removing your armed guards is a risky choice. 

Likewise if there's other large gangs of violent people, like gangs, who .

Answer (score 2):

#### Indirectly - we finish it for them

- 10 zombies appear in central America somewhere.
- Trigger happy 2nd amendment enthusiasts slaughter them and effectively contain the problem with only a few secondary infections.
- Because the zombies are technically still citizens (zombie condition has no legal basis), they weren't using lethal force to attack (zombies dont kill as per question), and the state in question didnt have stand-your-ground laws, "self defense" is not a defense against 2nd degree murder of a zombie. The heroes are charged with murder.
- Mass protests erupt from the controversial decision. The issue maps onto existing partisan lines. Politicians or police are accused of being secret zombies. Other politicians are accused of faking the zombie crisis to hide homicide of political enemies.
- Protests results in police brutality. Police have zombies on the mind and have more civilian deaths. Which escalates more and more.
- Eventually civil war.
- Other nations get sucked in to the conflict.
- Nukes.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 options.

Option 1: a slow transformation.

Imagine the cause of the zombie plague mutated. Early on it was excessively slow, allowing many people to be infected before people even realized what was happening. Symptoms of the zombie plague would initially be small, like lowered intelligence. You dont start murdering people just because they show lowered intelligence right?

Transmission of the plague early on can happen through scratches as well as bites. A symptom is nail-biting, depositing saliva on the nails before the soon-to-be zombie would be compelled to suddenly scratch nearby people. Some diseases can already influence people in similar ways.

The first big signs of the zombie plague is dozens of people being hospitalized for issues with their daily lives. Not eating right, loss of speech, trouble moving, impacted decision making, higher violence. By the time the WHO pinpoints what is happening millions of people across the world are infected, and looking for a cure has only just began. Hospitals become overrun with new cases, people want to take care of their loved one's so they keep infected inside in the hopes of protecting them. By the time zombie-ism is fully recognized and drastic, violent measures are taken its too late for the rest of the world. In the meantime the plague has evolved and the speed with which you lose your senses is now only 12 hours.

Option 2: a problem with a vaccine.

Imagine that they cant find the source of the zombie plague. Every so many weeks or months a few people are infected and become zombies, but whatever animal the plague use to jump to humans cant be found. The WHO investigates and eventually creates a vaccine. It looks so promising, but after about two years some residue of the vaccine, kept alive in the lymph nodes, mutates and infects the host. Millions are now infected.

Option 3: in the early stages it could infect insects as well.

Imagine if mosquito's could drink your blood and pass on this virus to other humans with almost 100% success. It would be a malaria on steroids. Not only that, but other insects that might eat the flesh of those poor souls who died can seek out other humans and bite them. Wasps and bees for example have ample bite force to breach your skin.

The plague mutated later on and is no longer transmittable through insects, but the damage has been done.